# Unregister broadcast receiver in the new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I want to ask, is it possible to unregister broadcast reciver in the new activity ?. For example, I click the button, register the receiver and then I go to the next activity. In new activity there is a button that I want to unregister this receiver and go back to main activity. Is there any way to implement it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using the `Application` class. Write the methods to register and un-register the receivers in the `Applicaiton` class and call them in respected `Activities`